# Stored payment methods not showing error message? Magento 2

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, messages, braintree

Stored Braintree credit card error message area not getting any message after failed order placement.

I found that The error message does show but in Braintree Credit card method, not in Stored credit card, which is being selected. So the message cannot be seen.

Any help would be appreciated.
I'm on Magento 2.4.1 by the way. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @long,

Did you get any solution?

Comment: any solution?, looks like a core bug